# jbpm business rule task example

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, business-rules, kie-workbench

Can some one provide me an working example for jbpm business rule task ? I tried creating one via jbpm work bench and executed via jbpmn eclipse plugin. It seems buiness process and rule task are not able to sync each other . Some times rule gets invoked, sometimes not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at this blog: [JBPM6 - RuleTask Example Using a Rule File](https://developer.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2013/12/20/jbpm6--ruletask-example-using-a-rule-file?_sscc=t)

The key is to make sure your *Rule Flow Group* in the Bussiness task matches the *Rule Flow Group* in the .drl file (from article in above link):

1. Business Rule Task:
   [image]
2. Business Rule:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Grady ! I followed the same. It was helpful

Answer (score 1):

On the top of that, I'd make sure that your Drools Rule and the jBPM process are stored in the same folder. There's a sample project here which demonstrates the usage: [Drools Rules with jBPM](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/drools-example-jbpm-5)